# Block (deny) the use of localStorage/sessionStorage by domain in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, local-storage

I know localStorage can be disabled entirely in Chrome, but is there a way to disable it *per site* (domain/URL)?

Blocking cookies doesn't do it, either using Chrome's built-in functionality or the EditThisCookie extension. If I go to Chrome Site Settings
[chrome://settings/content/siteDetails?site=*THE_SITE*] I can clear the contents there, but this is a bit annoying to do all the time and I want to prevent the site from storing data there in the first place.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to control websites' use of localStorage in Firefox?](https://superuser.com/questions/629525/how-to-control-websites-use-of-localstorage-in-firefox)

Comment: Alright, I'll make this specific to Chrome then.

Comment: The data in the link mostly applies also to Chrome. Read it.

Comment: I have read it. As I say in the question, blocking cookies for a site does not block LocalStorage for it in Chrome, at least in my experience.

Comment: According to all sources localStorage obeys cookies policy. If you think otherwise, you should report a bug in Chrome.

Comment: Is there an official source that says this - for Chrome - that I can point to in my bug report?